# Loading a view from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, youtube, controller

I have controller written in CodeIgniter

```
this->layout->view('pages/dashboard/youtubeupload')
```

This code is the part of YouTube video upload code. When I try running this Controller independently it works well. After the success, I have to redirect the controller to view as stated in the last line above.

code for the view:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
 echo "<p>You need to <a href='".$_SESSION['authUrl']."'>authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>";
```

The question is, how can I redirect from the controller to view in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand exactly what is `After the success` for you, the youtube upload video proccess or the simple execution of the controller? Or other thing that I missed?

Inside the controller you'll have many methods that will renderize any views, according with your validations you have the possibility to present error messages or simple redirect the user for a login page if a authenticate session is missing for example:

```
if($_SESSION['user'] == NULL) {
  redirect('/account/login', 'refresh'); // or other view
} else {
  this->layout->view('pages/dashboard/youtubeupload')
}
```

Can you explain more and post more code?

Comment: i have created a view and I am calling the controller from ajax . controller named YOutube -- uploads video from Form and then it call youtube API to upload it on Yoututbe server. Now because of youtube authentication -it ask to authorise the acccount (this part is what i want to put in view) , and once the condition is seen , redirecting the cotrol to the view from where user can authroize and upload starts.

Comment: thanks @lucas-keller, it helped somehow to achieve the required results.